# What is the new table name after joining two tables in sql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I read the previous posts but I couldn't find one that answered my question.
What would be the name of the table that is made by joining two tables? The reason why I need the name is because I would like to change the column name of the new table using the `ALTER TABLE (Table name) RENAME COLUMN (A) to (B).` If there is no specified name, how can I name the new table?

ex

```sql
SELECT
     client_id
    ,last_name
FROM INDIVIDUAL_CLIENT

UNION ALL

SELECT
     client_id
    ,bus_name
FROM BUSINESS_CLIENT;
```

I would like to rename the column to last_name/bus_name instead of last_name

Comment: A select query does not create a table , Also in a union the names supplied in the first select apply over all susequent selects (including aliases) https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html#union-result-set

Comment: You can use aliases for a column, and you can use a CTE to "name a query"(so to speak).

Comment: "What would be the name of the table" - why is that relevant? Why do you need the name of the table (while there is none) to rename a column (which you probably should not do in a `SELECT`  query)?

Answer (score 0):

In the case of a query what temporal table a query might create internally is not relevant, because you a making a query and getting data back, it doesn't stay in the database as a table, there is no such table. Unless we make it.

if You want TSQL to change a column name it would affect your union query and I base my answer on Your
'I would like to rename the column to last_name/bus_name instead of last_name'

And think this is what you're looking for. Please correct me if it isn't.
In generic SQL what we're doing is putting a label on both projections that are to be displayed in the same column

```
SELECT
     client_id
    ,last_name [last_name/ bus_name]
FROM INDIVIDUAL_CLIENT

UNION ALL

SELECT
     client_id
    ,bus_name [last_name/ bus_name]
FROM BUSINESS_CLIENT;
```

update, in MySQL notation uses AS and quotes instead of angle brackets

```
SELECT
     client_id
    ,last_name  as "last_name/ bus_name"
FROM INDIVIDUAL_CLIENT

UNION ALL

SELECT
     client_id
    ,bus_name as "last_name/ bus_name"
FROM BUSINESS_CLIENT;
```

Comment: How does this answer the question? Please make sure (especially when, as you point out, OP is inexperienced) you add explanation to your answer(s) so it's easy to see why you're doing what you are

Comment: I don't mind explaining, will update, though the asker is clearly trying to put two columns in the same column and give them a label saying this column holds both. I am sure it will make sense to her, because doing so works like she intended.

Comment: In MySQL object names which contain invalid characters should be enclosed with backticks not square brackets

Comment: oh yea it's mysql not tsql better update with that too @P.Salmon, thanks

Comment: @Manuel, disagree (<-  this is a personal opinion), we all start somewhere and as such, are inexperienced and need pointers, I agree that the opening sentence adds nothing, but by the same token, it doesn't take anything away either. Also, OP is not a "new user", going by profile (and posts), `Member for 2 years`, first question Feb 2021

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer but it's not working (also I'm not the one who downvoted). It says " You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[last_name/ bus_name] FROM INDIVIDUAL_CLIENT UNION ALL SELECT client_id ,bus_nam' at line 1"

Comment: @SoyoonMoon - replace square brackets (`[ \ ]`) with backticks `

Comment: @Manuel well i suppose you're right I have rephrased, no reason to come off with a smirk, when i'm slightly missing the database engine off the bat myself.

Comment: @CanO'Spam - Thank you so much!! It worked =D!! I made this account 2 years ago when I wasn't a college student (back then my question was so basic I was suspended for a week) - I decided to major in CS really recently, so I am a newbie ! Once again thank you all for your help.

Comment: @SoyoonMoon i made it work in my postgres with as and quotes, updated answer, i'm sorry i read SQL and immediately thought TSQL but it was not, anyway what you want to do is add label and i think updated example will work